# Field validation: check for uniqness

Tags: entities

There is this content type and it has a field (decimal). I want to apply a uniqueness validation on it (no two nodes with the same "National Code" value). Apparently Field Validation module is the way to go. How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with [Unique Field module](http://drupal.org/project/unique_field). Set the scope to Content Type and you should be good to go.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a module that is designed solely to cope with that

Answer (score 0):

I did it using the Field Validation module (`Unique Value` rule). It is pretty simple and gives you many other validation options that might come in handy.